# Sort Caret Not Displaying

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, wpf-style

I'm having a problem where I'm using a provided style (I can alter it) and most times I get the sort caret, but in one case I don't.

This is the style:

```
<Style x:Key="StyleDataGridHeader" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="x:Type DataGridColumndHeader}">
                <Grid x:Name="gridColumn background="{DynamicResource TableHeaderBackground}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock
                        x:name:"columnText" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="{DynamicResource TableHeaderBackground}"
                        Focusable="False" Foreground="{DynamicResource TableHeaderFontColor}" 
                        Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                    <Path
                        x:Name"SortArrow" Grid.Column="0" Width="10" Height="10"
                        Fill="{DynamicResource TableColumnHeaderCaretColor}"
                        Focusable="False"
                        Style="{StaticResource CaretIconLeft}"
                        Visibility="Collapsed" />
                    <Thumb
                        x:Name="PART_LeftHeaderGripper"
                        Style="StaticResource ColumnHeaderGripStyle" />
                </Grid>
                
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="SortDirection" Value="Ascending">
                        <Setter TargetName="SortArrow" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        <Setter TargetName="columnText" Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource TableColumnHeaderFocusColor}" />
                        <Setter TargetName="SortArrow" Property="LayoutTransform">
                            <Setter.value>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="180" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="SortDirection" Value="Decending">
                        <Setter TargetName="SortArrow" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        <Setter TargetName="columnText" Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource TableColumnHeaderFocusColor}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="columnText" Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource TableColumnHeaderFocusColor}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And here's an excerpt of the control with a column that works and a column that doesn't:

```
<UserControl
    ...
    <Grid ...
    
                                    <!-- This one works (sort caret displayed) -->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn 
            Width="50"
            SortMemberpath="ColA" 
            SortDirection="Ascending"
            CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellCenter}"
            HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridHeaderCenter}"
            Header="COL-A">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Path Style="{StaticResource CircleIcon}" Fill="{Binding ColA}" />
                </DataTemplate
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn 

                                    <!--  This one doesn't work  (sort caret not displayed) -->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn 
            Width="300"
            SortMemberpath="ColB" 
            SortDirection="Ascending"
            CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellCenter}"
            HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridHeaderCenter}"
            Header="COL-B">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding IconVals, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>   
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <controls:StandardButtonControl
                                    State="{Binding BState}"
                                    Label="{Binding BLabel}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl />
                </DataTemplate
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn 
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The case where it doesn't work is a little more complex, but I can't figure out what's missing; any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SortDirection which you check in your triggers could start off as Null, and thus your Path will stay with Visibility Collapsed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I think you;re ont something, but not exactly unitialized.  For grins I changed the style to <Path ... Visibility="Visible"> and all the carets showed up.  But the ColB column could not be triggered to change sort direction (clicking on the header did nothing).

Comment: That's a separate problem to the style. You could try instead of triggers, to use a converter, and bind the Path's visibility to it, to check what values you get. What is property ColB that you use as SortMemberPath? Can you show the model code? The sorting problem could be it.

Comment: Sorry for the delay - release end, mega snow, and laptop went belly up.  It was an invalid use of SortMemberPath for column-B (ColB); this column was actually a stackpanel of buttons with numbers in them and I don't think wpf knew what to do with that.  So I created a dummy column and pointed SortMemberPath to that and all was well.  Thanks!